# Enter entity property from the inversed side in one to one relation

Tags: php, doctrine, sonata-admin

Let's assume i have an one-to-one relation with one entity person

```
class Person
{
...
    /**
     * @var Player
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Player", inversedBy="person")
     */
    private $player;
...
}
```

and one entity Player

```
class Player
{
...
    /**
    * @var Person
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", mappedBy="player")
    */
    private $person;
...
}
```

Now the person side is holding the foreign key for the person.

Every try to access something from the inversed side is failing, for example

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Player')->findByPerson();
```

ends up in

> [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
>   You cannot search for the association field
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Player#person', because it is the inverse side of
>   an association. Find methods only work on owning side associations.

Doing the same to the owning side (find player for the person), everything is fine.

I cant figure out: How can i access entities from both sides?

I need that, because i need to know, which player hasn't already persons assigned and vice versa. I thought, doctrine is loading the related entities ... for this case plain sql seems the easier solution for that? Or have i really to deal with dql and joins?

Answer (score 0):

In your class Player, can you try with this :

```
class Player
{
...
    /**
    * @var Person
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Person", mappedBy="player")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $person;
...
}
```

Here is the doctrine doc: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

Comment: As i see, you only add the joinColumn part ... as the documentation says, its not necessary to add this as long as the key columns doesn't differ from it's naming scheme. The entry above will generate another column in the Player entity named "person_id" and connect this to the entity person "id" with a foreign key constraint ... thats not wanted, because a relation from Person->Player already exist from the other side (person.player_id = player.id) ...